# pull operation in mongoose is taking several attempts to delete a sub document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

i am developing a todolist application so that for each user i store the activities of a user in an array. schema of user look like this.

```
const activitySchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  activity:String
})

const Activity=new mongoose.model("activity",activitySchema)
const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  username:String,
  password:String,
  activities:[],
});
```

i used pull command to delete a specific activity from user actvities list

```
    app.post("/delete",(req,res)=>{
  User.updateOne( {username: req.user.username}, { $pull: { activities: { _id: req.body.activity} }
    }, function(err, model){
      if(err)
      console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log(model)
        res.redirect("/")
      }
    })
})
```

this code is working after user clicks for 5-10 times on delete button but not immediately. the log output showing matched document:1 and modified document:0. kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

For Modifying the document you need to save the model after making every change to the model.

```
activity.save().then(()=>{ console.log("Document Saved"))
```

Similar is the for the other document where you are making a change, You can read more about it  if you want [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save)